# UISearchDisplayController in iOS6: message sent to deallocated "_UISearchBarShadowView"

Tags: ios, ios6, uisearchdisplaycontroller

Edit2: Commented out tons of stuff and now it works! Now to put stuff back until it breaks again.

I haven't touched this app since like iOS 3 and all of a sudden I'm getting "message sent to deallocated instance" of "_UISearchBarShadowView" in iOS 6 when I try to search in a UISearchDisplayController. It's an old app so it's not using ARC.

Anyone else seen this? No idea what to do.

Running with NSZombiesEnabled I get:

```
[_UISearchBarShadowView frame]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x950ef70
(gdb) bt
#0  0x0280ca97 in ___forwarding___ ()
#1  0x0284977e in __forwarding_prep_1___ ()
#2  0x00c40421 in -[UISearchResultsTableView setContentOffset:] ()
#3  0x009d2ae6 in -[UIScrollView(Static) _adjustContentOffsetIfNecessary] ()
#4  0x009b58c2 in -[UIScrollView setContentSize:] ()
#5  0x009fbe3f in -[UITableView(_UITableViewPrivate) _updateContentSize] ()
#6  0x00a09fc4 in -[UITableView noteNumberOfRowsChanged] ()
#7  0x00a0992c in -[UITableView reloadData] ()
#8  0x00c4504c in -[UISearchDisplayController searchBar:textDidChange:] ()
#9  0x00b94d85 in -[UISearchBar(UISearchBarStatic) _searchFieldEditingChanged] ()
#10 0x025b4705 in -[NSObject performSelector:withObject:withObject:] ()
#11 0x00961873 in -[UIApplication sendAction:fromSender:toTarget:forEvent:] ()
#12 0x00a232ce in -[UIControl(Deprecated) sendAction:toTarget:forEvent:] ()
#13 0x00a22960 in -[UIControl(Internal) _sendActionsForEventMask:withEvent:] ()
#14 0x00a2f78c in -[UITextField fieldEditorDidChange:] ()
#15 0x00a39bf6 in -[UIFieldEditor webViewDidChange:] ()
#16 0x00642dc9 in __57-[NSNotificationCenter addObserver:selector:name:object:]_block_invoke_0 ()
#17 0x028770c5 in ___CFXNotificationPost_block_invoke_0 ()
#18 0x027d1efa in _CFXNotificationPost ()
#19 0x00577482 in -[NSNotificationCenter postNotificationName:object:userInfo:] ()
#20 0x06e7109e in WebThreadPostNotification ()
#21 0x05fc026a in WebEditorClient::respondToChangedContents ()
#22 0x063fb78c in WebCore::Editor::respondToChangedContents ()
#23 0x063fe588 in WebCore::Editor::appliedEditing ()
#24 0x06e4bd12 in WebCore::TypingCommand::typingAddedToOpenCommand ()
#25 0x06e4be4a in WebCore::TypingCommand::insertTextRunWithoutNewlines ()
#26 0x06e4c5c0 in WebCore::TypingCommandLineOperation::operator() ()
#27 0x06e4c3b8 in WebCore::forEachLineInString<WebCore::TypingCommandLineOperation> ()
#28 0x06e4ab02 in WebCore::TypingCommand::insertText ()
#29 0x063f8ac6 in WebCore::Editor::insertTextWithoutSendingTextEvent ()
#30 0x063f7d56 in WebCore::Editor::handleTextEvent ()
#31 0x0642b320 in WebCore::EventHandler::defaultTextInputEventHandler ()
#32 0x06a85afd in WebCore::Node::defaultEventHandler ()
#33 0x06421e66 in WebCore::EventDispatcher::dispatchEvent ()
#34 0x064230aa in WebCore::EventDispatchMediator::dispatchEvent ()
#35 0x0642101e in WebCore::EventDispatcher::dispatchEvent ()
#36 0x06a841aa in WebCore::Node::dispatchEvent ()
#37 0x0643b491 in WebCore::EventTarget::dispatchEvent ()
#38 0x0642b0ca in WebCore::EventHandler::handleTextInputEvent ()
#39 0x063ff03e in WebCore::Editor::insertText ()
#40 0x05ffc7fb in -[WebHTMLView(WebNSTextInputSupport) insertText:] ()
#41 0x025b46b0 in -[NSObject performSelector:withObject:] ()
#42 0x06e66ed0 in -[WAKResponder tryToPerform:with:] ()
#43 0x0603b384 in -[WebView(WebViewEditingActions) _performResponderOperation:with:] ()
#44 0x0603d4df in -[WebView(WebViewEditingActions) insertText:] ()
#45 0x00b1f254 in -[UIWebDocumentView insertText:] ()
#46 0x00ae204f in -[UIKeyboardImpl insertText:] ()
#47 0x00ae33b8 in -[UIKeyboardImpl addInputString:fromVariantKey:] ()
#48 0x00ae1f5e in -[UIKeyboardImpl handleStringInput:fromVariantKey:] ()
#49 0x00aec12d in -[UIKeyboardImpl handleKeyEvent:] ()
#50 0x0096f43b in -[UIApplication _handleKeyEvent:] ()
#51 0x00a6ce05 in -[UIResponder(Internal) _handleKeyEvent:] ()
#52 0x00a6ce05 in -[UIResponder(Internal) _handleKeyEvent:] ()
#53 0x00a6ce05 in -[UIResponder(Internal) _handleKeyEvent:] ()
#54 0x00a6ce05 in -[UIResponder(Internal) _handleKeyEvent:] ()
#55 0x00a6ce05 in -[UIResponder(Internal) _handleKeyEvent:] ()
#56 0x00a6ce05 in -[UIResponder(Internal) _handleKeyEvent:] ()
#57 0x00a6ce05 in -[UIResponder(Internal) _handleKeyEvent:] ()
#58 0x00a6ce05 in -[UIResponder(Internal) _handleKeyEvent:] ()
#59 0x00a6ce05 in -[UIResponder(Internal) _handleKeyEvent:] ()
#60 0x0096f495 in -[UIApplication handleKeyEvent:] ()
#61 0x0096ee66 in -[UIApplication handleEvent:withNewEvent:] ()
#62 0x0096f24b in -[UIApplication sendEvent:] ()
#63 0x00960cf8 in _UIApplicationHandleEvent ()
#64 0x034afdf9 in _PurpleEventCallback ()
#65 0x034afad0 in PurpleEventCallback ()
#66 0x02792bf5 in __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ ()
#67 0x02792962 in __CFRunLoopDoSource1 ()
#68 0x027c3bb6 in __CFRunLoopRun ()
#69 0x027c2f44 in CFRunLoopRunSpecific ()
#70 0x027c2e1b in CFRunLoopRunInMode ()
#71 0x034ae7e3 in GSEventRunModal ()
#72 0x034ae668 in GSEventRun ()
#73 0x0095e65c in UIApplicationMain ()
#74 0x00002fad in main (argc=1, argv=0xbffff39c) at /Users/mlin/repos/Apps/B-Rhymes/main.m:14
```

Edit: I took out the asyncing of the search to get a full stack trace. Weird that there's all this "WebCore" stuff.

Comment: Convert this thing to arc immediately.  The refactoring tool will probably, in turn, catch your over releasing problem as an error.

Comment: Hey, I ran it through the refactoring tool and I'm still getting this. Any other ideas?

Comment: Do you have `viewDidUnload` implemented? If so, any chance you're releasing or assigning `nil` to a view that you don't have a `strong` reference to?

Comment: Good call. Removed all my viewDidUnloads but still same issue. Edit: Made the search synchronous to get a full stack trace.

Comment: So when you say you ran it through the refactoring tool, does that mean the project is compiling with ARC?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. It was my own damn fault of course, but I'd forgotten because I hadn't looked at the code in years. I was messing around with internal views, to adjust the look of the search results. Thanks for the help!